# Miniconda for ARMv6 (Zero W)

Tags: python, pi-zero-w, arm, software-compilation

I want to install miniconda on my Zero W, but it has ARMv6 architecture and that does not seem to be supported by Continuum Analytics. See https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/ (just one outdated ARMv6 installer).

Is it reasonable to give it a shot at compiling it? What else do you suggest? I've tried `pip install conda` but that does not seem to be working...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Berryconda is the way to go!

See
https://github.com/jjhelmus/berryconda

Comment: It would be really helpful if people down voting answers would comment on why they did so.  This answer has a -1 rating, but it seems to answer the question clearly.

Comment: @Omegaman have my upvote to set the ballance

Comment: "This project is no longer active, no recipe will be updated and no packages will be added to the rpi channel."

Answer (score 2):

BerryConda supports raspbian/jessie, with a may/may not warning about other versions of raspbian.   jessie was replaced by stretch and now buster, which is required for Pi 4. [announcement of buster](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/buster-the-new-version-of-raspbian/)